# JavaScript - how to add alphas of 2 images so the result is alpha = 1?

Tags: javascript, image, addition, layer, alpha

I need to make a transition between two images - both images are masks that hide a sprite bellow. Part of each mask is white, part is transparent. I need the total alpha of both images to be 1 every time so it looks like the mask smoothly changes its shape.
If I use a transition of alpha from 1 to 0 for image1 and 0 to 1 for image2 and then draw both images over each other, then result isn't alpha1 + alpha2 = 1. Is there any way how to get it?
Thanks a lot,
Vaclav

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the default behaviour of the canvas, at the condition that the destination is the original image1 (not multiplied by alpha from 1 to 0).

The `source-over` operation does `result = alpha*source + (1-alpha)*dest`, even for the alpha channel.

I don't have mask images to test it, but I think this code should do what you want:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
ctx.globalAlpha = 1.;
ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
ctx.globalAlpha = ratio;
ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
```

(Some lines are unnecessary if you know in which state the context was before the computation)

---

(By the way, giving an example code to reproduce the problem in your question would be much appreciated)